# How to check SLURM environmental variables programmatically?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, slurm

How can I programmatically access SLURM environmental variables, like `MaxArraySize` or `MaxJobCount`? I would like to partition my job arrays into chunks of the allowed maximum size. Can this information be queried with any of SLURM's commands? So far, I have failed to find relevant information on this over the net. Finding `slurm.conf` on each machine and extract the relevant line from it is not a very robust solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ scontrol show config | grep -E 'MaxArraySize|MaxJobCount'
MaxArraySize            = 1001
MaxJobCount             = 1000000
```

Will that be enough for what you're wanting to do?

To get only the *value* for e.g. MaxArraySize:

```
$ scontrol show config | sed -n '/^MaxArraySize/s/.*= *//p'
```

As a shell function:

```
slurm_conf_value () {
    scontrol show config | sed -n "/^$1/s/.*= *//p"
}

MaxArraySize="$(slurm_conf_value 'MaxArraySize')"
```

These are not environment variables in the Unix sense, but configuration settings in Slurm. They are variables for configuring the "Slurm environment" though.

Comment: Ok, I was desperately searching for `scontrol show config` or similar in the docs, but obviously I overlooked it. Thanks, this will do perfectly!